# Delay AJAX from loading?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am programming an online PHP-based fantasy pet simulation game. I am not very familiar with AJAX, so please keep this in mind when answering.

On pet pages, I would like users to be able to feed/water/play with their pets without needing to reload the entire page - that's why I'm using AJAX. Here's what I have so far:

**Working Script**

```
$(function() {

$(".petcareFood").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#petcareFood").load($(this).attr("href"));
});

});

$(function() {

$(".petcareWater").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#petcareWater").load($(this).attr("href"));
});

});

$(function() {

$(".petcarePlay").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#petcarePlay").load($(this).attr("href"));
});

});
</script>
```

**Working HTML**

```
<a class=\"petcareFood\" href=\"petcare.php?pet=#&action=#\">Feed Your Pet</a>
<a class=\"petcareWater\" href=\"petcare.php?pet=#&action=#\">Water Your Pet</a>
<a class=\"petcarePlay\" href=\"petcare.php?pet=#&action=#\">Play With Your Pet</a>
```

NOW, everything that I listed above works like a charm! *This* is my problem: I want those links to also update another DIV - the one which contains updated status bars showing how hungry/thirsty/unhappy their pet is. Currently, I am doing that like this:

**The *Almost* Working Script**

```
$(function() {

$(".petcareFood").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#petcareHunger').load('ajax/hunger.php?pet=#');
});

});

$(function() {

$(".petcareWater").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#petcareThirst').load('ajax/thirst.php?pet=#');
});

});

$(function() {

$(".petcarePlay").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#petcareMood').load('ajax/mood.php?pet=#');
});

});
```

The script above makes it so that when a user clicks one of the HTML links, it updates two DIVS (one DIV containing the message displayed when a user feeds/waters/plays with their pet, and the other containing the status bar). Now... that *seems* all fine well and good, BUT... if both scripts update at exactly same time, then the PHP that handles the status bar is not updated - it's still retrieving old information.

My question to all of you is: Is there any way that I can delay running the second set of script (so that it will update after the PHP makes changes to MySQL)?

I tried inserting this before "the almost working script":

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('#petcareMood').load('ajax/mood.php?pet=#');
}, 2000);
```

However, it doesn't work. Well - it does, but just once. Users need to play with their pets at least 3 times a day to achieve 100% happiness, and so delaying the second DIV only once doesn't cut it for me. When I tried adding the same script multiple times, it just stopped working all together. What can I do?!

If you'd like to see screen shots of how things are working, please just ask. I will be happy to provide them upon request.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `setTimeout`, use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval). When it's no longer needed, you can kill it using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).

`setInterval` will execute a given function every `n` milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a hardcoded delay time, you maybe could use the callback function of the first ajax action:

```
//trigger first ajax
$("#petcarePlay").load($(this).attr("href"), function(){
  //trigger second ajax call, when first is completed
  $('#petcareHunger').load('ajax/hunger.php?pet=#');
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `complete` parameter to specify a callback function that gets executed when the request completes.  Then from within the callback, execute another request which actually updates the divs.

Example:

```
$(".petcareWater").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#petcareWater").load($(this).attr("href"), function(response, status, xhr) {
        // code here to make another request for stats
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could have the initial URLs return some JSON data that contain the updated stats so when a person does something to/with their pet, it returns all the stats so you can immediately update the div's all with one call rather than having to make a secondary call for the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but i think the ajax constructor is better for your purpose  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

There you can set that the AJAX will be synchronous(It will wait to finish the AJAX callback )

Here is a few theory about it :)

http://javascript.about.com/od/ajax/a/ajaxasyn.htm